# Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this) return always null

Tags: wpf, popup, controltemplate

I have a simple TextBox with the Style "AutoCompleteTextBox":

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox" Style="{StaticResource AutoCompleteTextBox}" />
```

The Style is located in my Resource Dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="AutoCompleteTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="False">
                        <ListBox x:Name="PART_ListBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In my Code Behind File I have two getters:

```
private Popup Popup
{
    get { return Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this) as Popup; }
}
private ListBox ItemList
{
    get { return Template.FindName("PART_ListBox", this) as ListBox; }
}
```

and the textbox load event:

```
void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var popup = Popup;

    var itemlist = ItemList;
}
```

Now I have the problem that `Popup` and `ItemList` returns always null, **why?**

Comment: `Loaded` might be too early, or the `this` is not the `TextBox` instance (which would also mean that the `Template` is not the one of the `TextBox`, where exactly are those code pieces?).

Comment: @H.B. When i try it later it's also return null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XAML you create a normal TextBox and style it, in code behind you have `this.Template` & `this`, how is that supposed to work? There is no way that `this` is actually the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 2):

By 'code behind', it looks like you are referring to the code-behind for your window or view: the thing that contains the text box. Therefore the `Template` property will refer to the template of this container, not of the text box. I would sub-class `TextBox` and expose the two properties on its code-behind, or specify that you're after the Template of the specific text box in question. i.e.:

```
private Popup Popup
{
    get { return TextBox.Template.FindName("PART_Popup", TextBox) as Popup; }
}
```

Comment: The `this` as method parameter is also off, if you search in a template you should pass the templated instance, which is the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , it is a strange problem. The code works fine for the first two buttons, but the third button give me an exception as the 'presenter; object is null !

```
ContentPresenter presenter = new ContentPresenter();
        presenter = buttonUsersSave.Template.FindName("Presenter", buttonUsersSave) as ContentPresenter;
        presenter.Content = "Save";
        presenter = buttonUsersUpdate.Template.FindName("Presenter", buttonUsersUpdate) as ContentPresenter ;
        presenter.Content = "Update";
        presenter = buttonUserAuthSave.Template.FindName("Presenter", buttonUserAuthSave) as ContentPresenter;
        presenter.Content = "Save";
```

Comment: buttonUserAuthSave button is placed at the second tabcontrol item , if I place it beside the other two buttons at the first tabcontrol item it works fine.